# Submit array with WordPress variables on form submit

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have a template that picks wordpress post variables from the db and loads them on a html template i designed.
what i want is for the user to select articles they like then submit the selection to a template which will intern be a newsletter.

so far i have the code that pics the data from the db and arranges them in my template . the code is as below:

```
        <?php /*
    Template Name: News Selector Template
    */
      //Pull the data
    $posts = $wpdb->get_results
    ("
    SELECT
        p1.*,
        wm2.meta_value 
    FROM
        mp_posts p1 
    LEFT JOIN
        mp_postmeta wm1
        ON (
            wm1.post_id = p1.id
            AND wm1.meta_value IS NOT NULL
            AND wm1.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
        )
    LEFT JOIN
        mp_postmeta wm2
        ON (
            wm1.meta_value = wm2.post_id
            AND wm2.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
            AND wm2.meta_value IS NOT NULL
        )
    WHERE
        p1.post_status='publish'
        AND p1.post_type='post'
    ORDER BY
        p1.post_date DESC LIMIT 0,30
    ");

    ?>


    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      <!--
      body {
        font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        background-color: #42413C;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        color: #000;
      }

      /* ~~ Element/tag selectors ~~ */
      ul, ol, dl { /* Due to variations between browsers, it's best practices to zero padding and margin on lists. For consistency, you can either specify the amounts you want here, or on the list items (LI, DT, DD) they contain. Remember that what you do here will cascade to the .nav list unless you write a more specific selector. */
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
        margin-top: 0;   /* removing the top margin gets around an issue where margins can escape from their containing div. The remaining bottom margin will hold it away from any elements that follow. */
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px; /* adding the padding to the sides of the elements within the divs, instead of the divs themselves, gets rid of any box model math. A nested div with side padding can also be used as an alternate method. */
      }
      a img { /* this selector removes the default blue border displayed in some browsers around an image when it is surrounded by a link */
        border: none;
      }
      /* ~~ Styling for your site's links must remain in this order - including the group of selectors that create the hover effect. ~~ */
      a:link {
        color: #42413C;
        text-decoration: underline; /* unless you style your links to look extremely unique, it's best to provide underlines for quick visual identification */
      }
      a:visited {
        color: #6E6C64;
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
      a:hover, a:active, a:focus { /* this group of selectors will give a keyboard navigator the same hover experience as the person using a mouse. */
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      /* ~~ this fixed width container surrounds the other divs ~~ */
      .container {
        width: 960px;
        background-color: #FFF;
        margin: 0 auto; /* the auto value on the sides, coupled with the width, centers the layout */
      }

      /* ~~ the header is not given a width. It will extend the full width of your layout. It contains an image placeholder that should be replaced with your own linked logo ~~ */
      .header {
        background-color: #FFF;
      }

      /* ~~ This is the layout information. ~~ 

      1) Padding is only placed on the top and/or bottom of the div. The elements within this div have padding on their sides. This saves you from any "box model math". Keep in mind, if you add any side padding or border to the div itself, it will be added to the width you define to create the *total* width. You may also choose to remove the padding on the element in the div and place a second div within it with no width and the padding necessary for your design.

      */

      .content {

        padding: 10px 0;
      }

      /* ~~ The footer ~~ */
      .footer {
        padding: 10px 0;
        background-color: #000;
        color:#FFF
      }

      /* ~~ miscellaneous float/clear classes ~~ */
      .fltrt {  /* this class can be used to float an element right in your page. The floated element must precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
        float: right;
        margin-left: 8px;
      }
      .fltlft { /* this class can be used to float an element left in your page. The floated element must precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
        float: left;
        margin-right: 8px;
      }
      .clearfloat { /* this class can be placed on a <br /> or empty div as the final element following the last floated div (within the #container) if the #footer is removed or taken out of the #container */
        clear:both;
        height:0;
        font-size: 1px;
        line-height: 0px;
      }
      -->
    </style></head>

    <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="header"><a href="example.com"><img src="/example/images/logo_main_300x100px.png" alt="logo" name="example_logo" width="300" height="100" id="logo" style="background-color: #FFF; display:block;" /></a> 
        <!-- end .header --></div>
      <div class="content">
        <h1>example Top 30 Articles</h1>
        <p>Select the articles you want to add to the newsletter</p>
        <table width="960" border="2" summary="A collection of all the articles">
          <caption>
          Article Selection
          </caption>

          <form action="http://samples.net/brands/design/newsletter/"  method="post">
          <tr>
        <th scope="col">Select</th>
        <th scope="col">Title</th>
        <th scope="col">Description</th>
        <th scope="col">Cover</th>
        <th scope="col">link</th>

          </tr>
          <?php
        if (have_posts($posts)) {
          // var_dump($posts); die();
          foreach($posts as $post) {            
            ?>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row"><input type="checkbox" name="article" value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" /></th>
              <td><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $post->post_excerpt; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo '<img src="https:sample.net/wp-content/uploads/'.$post->meta_value.'" width="100px" alt="" />'?></td>
              <td><?php echo $post->guid; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php 
          }
        }
          ?>

        </table>
        <div></div>

        <p><tr>
        <td>
        <div> <input name="Generate" type="submit" id="submitt" target="_blank" /></div>
        </form>


        </td>
        </tr></p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <!-- end .content --></div>
      <div class="footer">
        <p>samples Management System</p>
        <!-- end .footer --></div>
      <!-- end .container --></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

What i want to know is how i can submit an array containing the data items(post_title, post_excerpt, meta_value, guid) in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden input, and implode the array into the input

```
<input type="hidden" name="metas" value="<?php echo implode(',', $posts);?>">
```

Then on the backend, you can use explode to retrieve the values:

```
$posts = explode(',', $_POST['metas']);
```

Comment: So where will i place the hidden input so that it captures all my variables?

Comment: The hidden input is placed inside of your form and acts just as any other input would, only it's hidden.

Comment: Ok so when i do that my submit button disappears.

Comment: @XavierFox You probably just have some bad markup ... Double check

Comment: Warning: explode() expects at least 2 parameters.this is the error i get once the form submits to my other form

Comment: @XavierFox Updated the answer. The first parameter is just the delimiter used to reconstruct the array. Same for implode, add the delimiter.

Comment: Ok so i managed to sort out the small issue with the delimiter. and this new error pops up Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Comment: @XavierFox That means you're not passing in a valid array. Do a `print_r` on the `$posts` array and make sure it's a valid array